# To use two ethernet ports with the same subnet, problems with IP

Tags: linux, networking

I have a box with Linux Ubuntu 8.04 and 4 Ethernet ports. I enabled 2 ports, eth0 and eth1, and am trying to configure them with static IPs (eth0 = 192.168.0.205 and eth1 = 192.168.0.206).

If I plug 2 cables, one for each, I can to ping my equipment by each IP as expected. But, if I remove the cable from eth1, I still can ping both IPs still. After this I can  disable eth1 and the 2 IPs still will be available for me on eth0.

If I to plug the cable in eth1 there is no difference, just eth0 port workings.

I did a test, and if I configure the 2 IPs in distinct subnets this problem doesn't occur.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.  What do you want to achieve?

Comment: How did you configure the ports? Command line program or some sort of configuration utility?

Comment: I would like than eth0 had 192.168.0.205 ip and eth1 192.168.0.206, but both are controlled just by eth0.

Comment: I configured the ports by /etc/network/interfaces file and after i restarted the networking process with '/etc/init.d/networking restart' command.

Comment: To have multiple ip-addresses on one interface, add the 2nd address with `ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.0.206 up`. Next address goes with eth0:1 up to eth0:255. You can use the 2nd adapter to connect to a physical different LAN.

Comment: I don't think you actually asked a question.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because by default Linux consider an IP address as a property of the whole host, not just a particular interface; therefore an ARP request from outside (which will be received by both interfaces) will cause a reply from all interfaces, not just the one with the requested IP.

Look at [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/22253/ubuntu-linux-multiple-nics-same-lan-arp-responses-always-go-out-a-single-n/30648#30648) to a question similar to yours (there is also another way involving arptables described there).