# Multiple NICs with IPs from same network at Linux host respond to a single MAC

Tags: linux, networking, arp, mac-address

CentOS host is armed with multiple NICs. All NICs are bound to the same subnetwork (let it be 10.0.0.0/24). Their IP configuration is provided with DHCP server (as reservations).

While trying to get ARP entry remotely for some particular IP address belonging to some particular NIC (with `arp -a` from Windows host), I always get the same MAC address, which is equal to the host’s first interface MAC address (eth0), regardless of the real adapter’s MAC. Example:

```
adapter, ip, mac, arpcache entry:

eth0, 10.0.0.1, aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:00, aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-00

eth1, 10.0.0.2, aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:11, aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-00

eth2, 10.0.0.3, aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:22, aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-00

…
```

For Windows hosts in similar configuration I am getting different MACs for different adapters (according to the adapter’s configuration).

**Why do Linux hosts respond with single MAC? Why do Windows hosts act in opposite way? What are the reasons for such behavior?**

How to configure current major Linux distributions to respond with different MACs? I’ve read the similar topic [Ubuntu Linux - multiple NICs, same LAN... ARP responses always go out a single NIC](https://serverfault.com/questions/22253/ubuntu-linux-multiple-nics-same-lan-arp-responses-always-go-out-a-single-n), but proposed answers do not work for my CentOS 6.4 host - adapters above eth0 become unreachable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Linux kernel default implementation of IPv4 is base on 'weak host model':
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model

You can setup multiple routing tables, each with a separate default for the appropriate gateway, and rules to tell traffic from certain ips to use the appropriate route.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want the arp reply to be transmitted from the NIC that gets the request?

Put the following in your /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce = 2
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_ignore = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_announce = 2
```

And then run

```
sysctl -p
```

These rules ensure that arp requests are only responded to on the interface on which they arrived

Comment: Yes. While querying with arp IP address 10.0.0.2 assigned to eth1 which MAC=aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:11, I'm expecting to receive aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-11 in response. But in current configuration I'm receiving eth0's MAC instead.

Comment: With settings you provided adapters above eth0 become unreachable (no ping replies directly after `sysctl -p`) - as it stated in original question, it doesn't work for fresh CentOS 6.4.