# Dual NIC with IP on same subnet - ARP routing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-networking, netplan

First time for me coming across this situation for some reason, but I have two NIC's in a VM and need both connected to the same subnet as each IP will run host different but related services.

Previous configurations like this, I have just had two IP's on a single NIC (eg: eth:0, eth:1). However, when trying to do as eth0 and eth1, I am struggling.

Done a lot of reading and can see and (broadly) understand the problem in terms of routing challenges created by the configuration.

Most of the articles that I have read have instructions for older Linux/Ubuntu versions, whereas I am using a newer version with Netplan. Have tried translating the older configuration instructions into Netplan world, but am not getting any success.

For example, when I do a "ping -I 10.10.10.10 www.google.com", not getting a response, which is indicating a setup / routing / arp routing issue (obviously). Has anyone done what I am trying to achieve with a Netplan configuration and can share steps / configuration necessary to achieve (as well as any other configuration required such as correct settings for net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_filter (or equivalent?)

My Netplan is below for reference. I would also like to know if doing this and changing ARP filtering defaults is a good/bad idea? Are there any drawbacks from either a security or other perspective?

Thanks,
Jab

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            addresses:
            - 10.10.10.73/27
            dhcp4: no
            routes:
            - from: 10.10.10.73
              on-link: true
              to: 0.0.0.0/0
              via: 10.10.10.65
              metric: 100
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 8.8.8.8
                - 8.8.4.4
        eth1:
            addresses:
            - 10.10.10.74/27
            dhcp4: no
            routes:
            - from: 10.10.10.74
              on-link: true
              to: 0.0.0.0/0
              via: 10.10.10.65
              metric: 1000
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 8.8.8.8
                - 8.8.4.4
    version: 2
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/900385/ghost-ping-on-a-multi-nic-linux-system/900958#900958

Comment: LIFE SAVER!!! Thanks!