# Cent OS not work with 2 Interface and same subnet

Tags: linux, networking, centos

[Please see the illustration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2MB3.png)

OS: Centos 7
Device A tranfer file to Linux .11
Device B tranfer file to Linux .12.
Both Interface is same subnet and don't have defualt gateway.

Issue:
On interface .12 not have traffic from device b but when i shutdown port of device A on switch traffic will move to interface .12

Comment: Please paste output of command `ip -4 r ls table all` and `nstat -az  TcpExtIPReversePathFilter`

Comment: related: https://serverfault.com/questions/900385/ghost-ping-on-a-multi-nic-linux-system